# dividing in bash script with digits

Tags: bash

I want to dive integers but my results would be a digit bash can't do digits:

```
from=69;to=64;steps=$(( 12-1 )); ssize=$(( (to - from) / steps ))
echo $ssize $steps
```

results

```
0 11
```

Edit:

bc works with multiplication:

```
echo "5.94*11.14" | bc
```

gives `66.17`

but division

```
echo "5.94/11.14" | bc
```

gives `0`

Comment: What did you expect that `echo` to produce? `ssize` is zero because bash only does integer arithmetic (-5/11 = 0)

Comment: I see, I thought bc can solve the issue but also bc can only multiply with digits

Comment: What? Show an example of bc

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: You can set the precision for bc. Either `echo "scale=3; 5.94/11.14" | bc` or `echo "5.94/11.14" | bc -l`

Comment: Teach bash integer division with floating point results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858

Comment: Related: [Bash only gives integer as output regardless of input when performing calculations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108328/bash-only-gives-integer-as-output-regardless-of-input-when-performing-calculatio), [Why does division in bash arithmetic compute most percentages as 0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825574/why-does-division-in-bash-arithmetic-compute-most-percentages-as-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already pointed out, bash cannot handle floating point calculation by itself. You're doing a floor-division

```
(69-64)//11 = 5//11 = 0
```

Instead use `bc`

```
steps=12;ssize=$(bc -l <<< "from=69;to=64;(to - from)/$steps;"); echo $ssize $steps
```

The option `-l` will load the mathlib and with it set `scale=20` telling `bc` how many digits after the period to handle. The default is `0`, that's why you're also seeing only integer division when invoking `bc` without `-l`. Alternatively set `scale` manually

```
steps=12;ssize=$(bc <<< "scale=20;from=69;to=64;(to - from)/$steps;"); echo $ssize $steps
```